# can someone help me find the correct syntax for this sql query? using node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, get, parameter-passing

im struggling to find the correct way to write this database request by email column i hope someone could point me in the right direction

```
const loginUser = async (request, response) => {let params = [request.body.email];let sql = SELECT * FROM vacations.users where email=${params}
```

`let user = await connection.executeWithParameters(sql, params)`
`console.log(user);`
`return user;`
`}`

i tried to include the parameters in several ways but i don't know how to correctly put them in the sql query

Comment: mssql or mysql .... ? which npm you are using?

Comment: using axios with mysql

Comment: node mysql2 npm package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: this way you can solve it very easily.